# Can I use plupload multiple queues in wordpress?

Tags: front-end, performance, plupload

I have a frontend upload form where users can upload images for their posts and I am using Plupload for it.

Since the next upload only starts once the previous upload is finised and the preview appears, it takes quite a while to upload only a couple of images. The upload is fast, but wp processing before the preview can be shown takes like 40 seconds even for a 2MB image and the server I am using is not slow and has little load.

I was wondering if it is possible to have parallel or threaded uploads in wordpress with plupload? I found this parameter: `[multiple_queues=true]`, but read somewhere that it is not available in WordPress.

So my question is, is it really not available in wordpress to use plupload multiple queries? And if so, is there a way to do parallel uploads some other way? Or what else can be done to speed things up?

Comment: you could modify the code to store all the files and then process them at the end instead, but then consider what if it times out then you lose all uploads? otherwise, it is entirely possible to implement the standard plupload with a custom implementation (I have done it before) but it could be a fairly involved process.